# check of the data is saved on the CoreData or not

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

i have a string called "word" and i stored this string into a an entity called **Lose** inside an attribute **word**, 
i want when the user save a string "word" again it will overwrite the current value not sitting a duplicate one, how to do that ?

what i have done so far:

```
        //save the data to core data
        let library = Lose(context: savecatch.context)
        library.word = "word"
        savecatch.saveContext()
```

before the saving i need to check if "word" is already exist or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch the record with the given attribute, then modify it and save it

```
let query = "word"
let request = NSFetchRequest<Lose> = Lose.fetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "word == %@", query)
do {
   let result = try context.fetch(request)
   if let found = result.first {
       found.word = "word"
       context.save()
   }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```